# How to mock a static filed's void method executed?

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

```
public class A { 
    public static B b = new B();
}

public B{
  public void method(Interface arg){}
}

public C {
  public void method2 (Object arg2){

    InterfaceInstance d = new InterfaceInstance;
    A.b.method(d);
  }
}
```

I wanna test if the A.b.method() is executed in Class C's method method2().
How can I mock? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different point of view:

*static* is an abnormality in good OO designs. You should have very good reasons to come up with static fields that you want to call methods on. Because they force you to use PowerMock(ito) to get it tested.

So: instead of turning to the "big" PowerMock hammer to somehow enable you to test hard-to-test code; consider stepping back and improving your design!

Meaning: *static* calls create direct, low level coupling between your classes. That is something that you really want to avoid for "real world" applications.

Comment: If I could modified the code, I wouldn't ask it here

Comment: @wmmj23 You wouldn't believe how many times I heard the opposite. In that case, kuhajeyan's answer will probably help you more.

Answer (score 2):

It can be like this,

```
 PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
 ArgumentCaptor<Object> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Object.class);
 PowerMockito.doNothing().when(
               A.class, "method", captor.capture());//mock static

 C c = new C();
 c.method2(new String("Mock"));

 PowerMockito.verifyStatic(times(1));
 Object obj = captor.getValue();//if you want check the object passed
```

Comment: org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.MethodNotFoundException: No method found  with parameter types

Comment: I've changed my code. The method arg is designed as interface. But in method2  a instance of the interface been created. I cannot use interface.class in ArgumentCaptor.forClass

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to resolve your issue:

- Suppress [static initialisation](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior) for the class A
- [Mock constructor](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor)

As for me, I prefer in this case use suppress static initialisation, because it's give me more control.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class) 
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("classapackage.A")
public class Test{
    @Mock
    private B bMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
       // if A.b public 
       A.b = bMock
       // if b private 
       org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.setInternalState(A.class,"b", bMock);
    }
}
```

I haven't checked code. It's general idea how you issue could be resolve.